# Java MouseListener not always working

Tags: java, swing, awt, jdialog, mouselistener

I find it odd that in my project, the mouselistener is not always heard. Has anyone else come across this? Or am I doing something wrong? I have to sometimes click it several times before it opens. I do wait between clicks to see if it is a performance issue.

```
JButton btnPin = new JButton("Pin");
btnPin.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if(staffPinDialog == null || staffPinDialog.isShowing() == false)
            staffPinDialog = new StaffPinDialog(idClicked);                 
    }
});
```

StaffPinDialog is a JDialog, where the reference has been created elsewhere. idClicked is also always initialized.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `mouseClicked(...)` doesn't always get called with each press of the mouse button, and in particular doesn't get called if the mouse moves between press and release. `mousePressed(...)` or `mouseReleased(...)` are better, but having said that, you shouldn't be using MouseListeners at all in this capacity but rather should be using ActionListeners (as per JB Nizet's answer) or AbstractActions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not supposed to use a MouseListener to detect button clicks. Use an ActionListener instead.

This will also have the additional advantage of being able to click the button using the keyboard.

Comment: ...and will turn off the listener automatically if `setEnabled(false)` is called on the button, and is more in line with the use of Actions -- more robust listener objects that have more behaviors and states than ActionListeners and are easily shared among buttons.  1+